# Mode of the $ \chi^2 $ distribution

Tags: mode, chi-squared-distribution

I've been studying a statistics textbook that makes a claim that the $ \chi^2 $ distribution with $ k $ degrees of freedom has a mode at $ k - 2 $ without proof. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) seems to agree) Why is this? Is there a geometric, or even algebraic way, to understand this statement?

Comment: Look at the wikipedia page for mode.  The mode occurs at the highest peak of a continuous distribution which can be found using calculus.

Comment: True. That doesn't seem very intuitive, though. (I'll be honest, taking a derivative of the gamma function is pretty nasty; I can't say I can do it. Thank goodness [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5CGamma%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%7D%5C;+x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7B2%7D-1%7D+e%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5C,) can.)

Comment: You don't need to take the derivate of the Gamma function, since it is not a function of $x$.

Comment: Good point; $ k $ is a parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pdf of a $\chi^2_k$ distribution is,
$$f(x) = 2^{-k/2} \Gamma{(k/2)}^{-1} x^{k/2 - 1}e^{-x/2}. $$

We need to find $x^*$ such that $x^* = \arg \max_\limits{x > 0} f(x)$. Then $x^*$ is the mode. Note that $\arg \max_\limits{x > 0} f(x)  = \arg \max_\limits{x > 0} \log f(x)$, so we will find the mode by maximizing the log of the pdf instead of maximizing the pdf (this turns out to be easier).

\begin{align*}
\log f(x) &= -\dfrac{k}{2} \log 2 - \log \Gamma(k/2) +  \left(\dfrac{k}{2} - 1 \right) \log x - \dfrac{x}{2}\\
\dfrac{\log f(x)}{dx}  &= \left(\dfrac{k}{2} - 1 \right) \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{2} \overset{set}{=} 0\\
\Rightarrow x^* &= k-2 
\end{align*}

Thus we get that the mode is $x^* = k-2$. If $k \leq 2$, then the mode is $0$, since the $\chi^2$ pdf in that case is decreasing on the positives.

EDIT: To verify that the second derivate is negative, look at @MatthewGunn's comment below.

Comment: Elaborating a bit, the 2nd derivative of $\log f$ is $-\left(\frac{k}{2} - 1 \right) x^{-2}$ hence, the pdf is log-concave everywhere iff $k \geq 2$. Thus the first order condition $x^* = k - 2$ achieves a maximum when $k \geq 2$.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this. I couldn't find it on multiple online searches.

Comment: +1. Plus, we can of course disregard the $2^{-k/2}\Gamma(k/2)^{-1}$ multiplicative constant from the very start (although it also drops out in the differentiation).

Comment: I can't disagree that you're right. I guess I should have phrased it as a question about [intuition](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/what-is-the-intuition-behind-a-result?cb=1), rather than a geometry/algebra argument. I'll accept this answer though since it answers the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Greenparker is correct and the double derivative can be proved to be less than 0. Substitute x=k-2    ->    k=x+2   in the 2nd derivative solution obtained (i.e. 
-(((x+2)/2)-1)*x^-2)

Thus we get, (-x/2)*(x^-2) which is negative. hence double derivative is negative.